# How to catch unexpected error that make the application clash and terminated?

Tags: c#, exception, error-handling

I develop a desktop application that have to save running process with xml file.
I have design and test already.

But I want to know how the catch the unexpected error that will make the application terminated to start save the running process.

Comment: Are you trying to write a program like Dr. Watson?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's possible the following links may help:

- http://www.csharp-examples.net/catching-unhandled-exceptions/
- http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/csharp-tutorial-dealing-with-unhandled-exceptions

You're (I believe) looking to bind to [AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.unhandledexception.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You want to use the `try / catch` construct.  Basically you wrap the code you are concerned is going to error in a `try { }` block and then immediately following is a `catch { }` block of code that will run if an error was encountered.  In this section you could do things like log the error, attempt to save to a different location, etc.

Refer to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0yd65esw%28v=vs.80%29.aspx for examples and information.

Answer (score 0):

If your application is a web application, you can handle it in this manner:

```
//Method in global.asax.cs
void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{ 
      var lastError = Server.GetLastError();
      //Log it using log4net 
}
```

Additionally you can consider using [elmah](http://code.google.com/p/elmah/)